# nginx не делает перенаправление

Tags: nginx

ВСем привет.
У меня есть nginx который я тщетно уже полдня пытаюсь настроить на проксирование запросов.
Есть 2 сервера с api и логикой сайта. они должны быть за nginx-ом.
Я делаю на стороне nginx в папке `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.ru` запись следующего вида

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443;
    ssl_sertificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.ru/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.ru/privkey.pem;
    server_name domain.ru;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8282;
    }
}
```

На localhost:8282 находится сервер с сайтом.

И так же у меня есть поддомен `api.domain.ru` и для него я делаю отдельный файл в `/etc/nginx/sites-available/api.domain.ru` со следующим содержимым:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443;
        ssl_sertificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.ru/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.ru/privkey.pem;
        server_name api.domain.ru;
    
        root /var/www/html;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8383;
        }
    }
```

А на 8383 порту у меня второй сервер уже с api к которму иногда редиректит с порта 8282.

Когда при таких настройках я пытаюсь подключиться к domain.ru из браузере, то получаю ошибку 521 от cloudflare(на котором у меня dns-ы).

Дополнительные условия:

- У меня закомментированы все строчки в `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
- Через ufw открыты порты 8282, 8383, 443, 80
- На роутере естесственно настроено перенаправление
- Если раскомментировать в `/etc/nginx/sites-available/defualt` блок server и добавить в `location /` строку `proxy_pass http://localhost:8282;` (только для domain.ru)  при условии что в строке listen находится 80 а не 443, то nginx перекидывает на 8282 и сайт работает, но мне нужно чтобы было 443 и отдельные файлы для блоков server так как если добавлять listen 443 в нескольких блоках server файла default то nginx ругается на `duplicate directive listen 443` и не получается установить сертификаты для всех поддоменов(хотя я специально сделал wildcard сертификат).
- В Cloudflare есть ресурсная запись для api.domain.ru и для domain.ru

Чарoдеимастера, хэлп, не могу двигаться дальше в обучении поку не настрою nginx, спасайте))

Comment: Если вы получаете ошибку от cloudflare, значит на нём не только dns-ы, а вы выполняете проксирование всех запросов через cloudflare (иначе он бы физически не смог выдать свою ошибку)

Comment: «открыты порты 8282, 8383» — вот этого точно не надо, иначе пропадает весь смысл использования nginx

Comment: А ещё странно, что ваш nginx почему-то не слушает порт 80, а на IPv6-порту 443 вы почему-то не включили ssl

Comment: @andreymal сейчас тоже пришел к выводу что возможно это изза проксирования на стороне днс поставщика. Отключил проксирование у него и попробую чуть позже еще раз обратиться к серверу с откорректированными по вашим замечаниям настрокими))

Comment: @andreymal а зачем мне может понадобится 80 порт слушать? это может влият на работоспособность сервера?(если подключение предполагается только по https)

Comment: Во-первых, самое первое подключение всегда идёт по порту 80 без https (если вы только не добавите свой сайт в HSTS Preload List или не заставите посетителей прописывать https в адресе вручную). Во-вторых, если в настройках Cloudflare отключено использование https при проксировании (а оно по умолчанию вроде бы отключено), то он будет стучаться в порт 80, а если этого порта нет, то вполне логично, что он выдаёт ошибку 521

Comment: Если планируется использование только https, то можно сделать один универсальный конфиг для порта 80, который будет редиректить все запросы на https, примерно такой: `server { listen 80 default_server; listen [::]:80 default_server; server_name _; location / { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; } }`

Comment: @andreymal Вот я так пытался сделать, но некоторые middleware-ы моего сайта делают редирект на api и в таком случае, браузер ловит `error too many redirects`, поэтому пока ччто не знаю как такое добавить((

Comment: @andreymal  я же проавильно понимаю , что редирект нужно делать в default_server в файле default? получается что это будет единстенная запись в этом файле?

Comment: Неважно в каком файле, идея в том, что default_server будет принимать на себя все запросы, которые не попали в другие секции server

Comment: Если у вас в cloudflare был отключен https для проксирования, то вполне логично, что он стучался только на порт 80 и не получал ничего кроме редиректов. Если у вас проблема повторяется даже после полного отключения проксирования на cloudflare, то, видимо, нужно искать, кто, где, и почему генерирут http-ссылки и менять их на https-ссылки

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо за оперативную помощь, буду пробовать)

Comment: @andreymal и проскирование у cloudflare убрал и прослушивание 80 порта добавил. Не знаю, что именно помогло, но теперь все идеально работает). Если оставите ответ, я его помечу галкой)